# Extract specific row and put it on the first row bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

How to extract one row if it contains specific characters such as "|" and put it on the first row?

For example:

```
varl="This is the first row (I might be specific)
...
This is the ith row (I might be specific)
...
this row contains I|am|sepcific|
...
This is the last row (I might be specific)
"
```

The output should look like:

```
varl="this row contains I|am|sepcific|
This is the first row (I might be specific)
...
This is the ith row (I might be specific)
...
...
This is the last row (I might be specific)
"
```

The specific row could be present in any row.

What I did is a bit messy and didn't get the right result:

```
new_varl=`echo "$varl" | grep '|'`\n`echo "$varl" | grep -v '|' `
```

But the result is :

```
new_varl="this row contains I|am|sepcific|\nThis is the first row (I might be specific)
...
This is the ith row (I might be specific)
...
...
This is the last row (I might be specific)"
```

`\n` didn't work as a carriage return

Comment: What is the expected output if more than one row contains the `|` character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` is not a Carriage Return, it's a linefeed. Carriage Return is `\r` and a newline is either `\n` or `\r\n` or `\n\r` depending on your platform. On Unix it's `\n`.

You can't grep for a linefeed in text that's separated by linefeeds. grep is applying the regexp to 1 line at a time and by definition a line is separated from other lines by linefeeds and so cannot contain a linefeed.

Using any awk:

```
awk '/\|/{ print; next } { tail=tail $0 ORS } END{ printf "%s", tail }'
```

e.g.:

```
$ echo "$varl"
This is the first row (I might be specific)
...
This is the ith row (I might be specific)
...
this row contains I|am|sepcific|
...
This is the last row (I might be specific)
```

```
$ varl=$( echo "$varl" | awk '/\|/{ print; next } { tail=tail $0 ORS } END{ printf "%s", tail }' )
```

```
$ echo "$varl"
this row contains I|am|sepcific|
This is the first row (I might be specific)
...
This is the ith row (I might be specific)
...
...
This is the last row (I might be specific)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your command, besides being too complicated (a long pipeline and nested back-quotes), is that it tries to use `n` as a command and that it uses `echo` which, under some circumstances, may modify the data it's outputting.

This replaces the value in `varl` with all the lines that contains `|` followed by all lines that does not contain `|`:

```bash
varl=$( grep    -F '|' <<<"$varl"
        grep -v -F '|' <<<"$varl" )
```

or

```bash
varl=$( grep -F '|' <<<"$varl"; grep -v -F '|' <<<"$varl" )
```

- The `-F` option forces `grep` to treat the pattern expression as a string (not as a regular expression).
- The `<<<"..."` thing is a non-standard feature of `bash` and some other shells called a "here-string".  It feeds the given string to the command on the command's standard input stream. As a standard alternative, you should pipe the input from `printf '%s\n' "$varl"`, but not `echo "$varl"` (see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)).
- Two commands that should be run unconditionally and in sequence may be separated with a literal newline, or by `;`.

Looking again at your attempted command (which, by the way, can't have produced the output that you show), it strikes me that you may have tried to use `\n` as a separator between the two `echo`+`grep` pipelines. As shown above, use `;` instead, or a literal newline.

Answer (score -1):

```
new_varl=`echo "$varl" | grep '|'`$'\n'`echo "$varl" | grep -v '|' `
```

Answer (score -2):

Put it in quotes.

```
new_varl=`echo "$varl" | grep '|'`"\n"`echo "$varl" | grep -v '|' `
echo "$new_varl"
```

For tasks like this, it is better to work with intermediate variables:

```
var_s=`echo "$varl" | grep '|'`
var_ns=`echo "$varl" | grep -v "$var_s"`
new_varl="$var_s\n$var_ns"
```

Easier to read and maintain. It is a matter of taste of course, but that particular error in the one-liner become very easy to notice and solve.

Comment: got the same result. `\n` didn't work as a carriage return

Comment: @Jiao Check the quotes. They are important in this case.

Comment: Note that e.g. `a="111\n222"` will insert `\n` as the two characters ``\`` and `n` into the variable.

Comment: I checked, but it only worked if the `$` ahead the `"\n"`